# Grails query cache is ignored

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have an application which is read-mostly, so most queries use the Hibernate 2nd-level query cache. I have one query that must be executed every time a page loads, so I invoke it from the layout GSP like this:

```
${Book.countByApproved(true, [cache: true])}
```

I have enabled the 2nd-level cache for the `Book` class, by adding

```
static mapping = {
    cache true
}
```

to `Book.groovy`. I also have the following configured in `DataSource.groovy`

```
hibernate {
  cache.use_second_level_cache = true
  cache.use_query_cache = true
  cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
```

In this same file I've enabled query logging by adding `logSql=true` in the `dataSource` block.

Every time I load a page, the `Book.countByApproved(true)` query is logged, so I assume this means that the results are not being retrieved from the query cache? I'm running everything locally, so there's no possibility that the cache is being missed because the cached query results have expired.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using the [Hibernate Filters plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) and have a default filter configured for the `Book` class. Perhaps there's some issue with using hibernate filters and the query cache?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken. there's a question exactly equals to yours, and the advice was to not use querys in GSPs. Try this in a filter and see if the cache works.

Comment: I occurred to me that queries in GSPs mightn't be cached, so I tried moving it into the controller (temporarily), but it still didn't seem to use the cache. Do you have a link for this other question?